Deleting data from the sqlite3 database Python-Flask
I want the data to be deleted from my database and table when the delete button next to the Doctor in the table is clicked (code provided below). please help me do that, that would mean a lot.
d_admin.html:
<div class="sil">
        <h1>Doktor Sil</h1>
        <form action="#">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col">Doktor ID</td> 
                        <td scope="col">Ad</td> 
                        <td scope="col">Soyad</td> 
                        <td scope="col">Uzmanlık Alanı</td> 
                        <td scope="col">Telefon</td> 
                        <td scope="col">Doğum Tarihi</td> 
                        <td scope="col">-</td>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for doktor in doktorlar %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{doktor[0]}}</td>
                        <td>{{doktor[1]}}</td>
                        <td>{{doktor[2]}}</td>
                        <td>{{doktor[4]}}</td>
                        <td>{{doktor[5]}}</td>
                        <td>{{doktor[6]}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="submit" href="admin_panel_menu/{{panel_id}}/sil/{{ doktor[0] }}"> - Sil - </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %} 
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

app.py:
@app.route('/admin_panel_menu/<panel_id>')
@app.route('/admin_panel_menu/<panel_id>/sil/<doktor>')
def admin_panel_menu(panel_id, doktor=None):
    # content_id'ye göre ilgili içeriği gönder
    if panel_id == 'Doktor':
        doktorlar = Doktor.doktor_goster()
        if doktor:
            Doktor.doktor_sil(doktor)
        return render_template('d_admin.html', doktorlar = doktorlar)
    if panel_id == 'Hasta':
        return render_template('h_admin.html')
    if panel_id == 'Rapor':
        return render_template('r_admin.html')

doktor.py:
def doktor_goster():
        conn = sqlite3.connect('hospital.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM Doktorlar")
        doktor = c.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        return doktor
    
    def doktor_sil(doktor_id):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('hospital.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE FROM Doktorlar WHERE id = {0}".format(id))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

I want to use the doctor_delete function here.
